# Java Invalid Assignment Operator

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the method references of Java 8. However, Eclipse says I'm using an invalid assignment operator instead of accepting the reference. I do not realize what my mistake is. Thanks!

```
public static void printAlumnes(Curs curs)
{
    String string = alumnesLlista.values().stream()

    .filter(alumne -> alumne.getCurs().equals(curs))
    .map(Alumne::toString())
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ; "));
```

Comment: `.map(Alumne::toString)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Alumne::toString()` is not valid syntax for a method reference. It should be `Alumne::toString` (i.e. no parentheses)